# How can I see measurement protocol hits in server-side GTM's preview mode?

Tags: google-tag-manager, server-side, google-analytics-4, measurement-protocol

I'm debugging measurement protocol hits to a server-side GTM container (from Insomnia, but tested with curl as well), but don't see them showing up in the container's preview mode. How can I see these?

For example:

```sh
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"client_id": "1234.5678", "events": [{"name": "test"}]}' 'https://gtm.example.com/mp/collect'
```

Answer (score 1):

Found it:

Add the `X-Gtm-Server-Preview` header with the value you can find from "⋮" > "Send requests manually"